# Batch Change File Names in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filenames, batch-processing, batch-rename

I have 200 JPEG images numbered from 1200 to 1399. How do I change their names from `1200.jpg`-`1400.jpg` to `1.jpg`-`200.jpg`, while keeping the original order of the image names?

Comment: Why Matlab? why are you not just using the batch conversion of the freeware tool [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/). Definitely faster than a Matlab solution. If you insist using Matlab, it can easily done with [`movefile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movefile.html) - put it in a loop and thats it.

Comment: because its part of my main function and I have to do it in matlab cause my function is written in matlab too. Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem which can be tackled more efficiently in bash or other shell scripting languages. Probably, it can even be solved just via a single shell `find`.

Anyway, matlab can also do the job.

Consider this.

```
list = dir('./stack*.png'); % # assuming the file names are like stack1200.jpg

offset = -1200;  # % numbering offset amount

for idx = 1:length(list)   % # we go through every file name

    name = list(idx).name;   
    number = sscanf(name,'stack%f.png',1);   % # we extract the number
    movefile(name,['stack' num2str(number + offset) '.png' ]);   % # we rename the file.

end
```

Comment: because its part of my main function and I have to do it in matlab cause my function is written in matlab too. Thanks for the Idea. but I dont get the offset part. because without that also movefile would be work and dont need also to num2str.  Thanks

Comment: @Sam What? There's no way around `num2str` or `sprintf` unless you want to manually write out all 200 file names without a loop. By assigning offset as a variable instead of hardcoding it, you can use the same script or function to bump the file names back 1,2,3... or 1200 indices. Although to make rename `stack1200.jpg` to `stack1.jpg`, you may want to use `offset = -1199`.

Comment: @Doresoom I have used beneath code with sprintf and of course in the loop and its working well. and no need for any offset stuff.

Comment: Yes, but you have no way of mapping the existing file names back to the originals. Yes, your solution is a perfectly acceptable one, but it just grabs whatever files were in the folder and arbitrarily renames them starting at 1. If you wanted to look back and be able to tell if you started with files 1100-1300 or 1200-1400, you'd have no way of knowing. Maybe it's not relevant to your situation, but @Acorbe's solution is more robust.

Answer (score 0):

I have find this solution which is quiet straightforward.

```
Pathfold= ('Path\to\images\');
dirData = dir('path\to\images\*.jpg'); 
fileNames = {dirData.name}; 
for i = 1:size(fileNames)  
    newName = sprintf('%d.jpg',i);
    movefile(fileNames{i},[Pathfold , newName]) %# Rename the file
end
```